# Checkbox selection with listview

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android : check box selection problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120207/android-check-box-selection-problem)

I'm trying to select all my checkboxes in the layout, when I'm pressing 'check all' button. I've done a list and placing a checkbox with that list.

Now, I want to select all my checkboxes in the layout using button click. How can I proceed to this?

(Important : I'm placing only one checkbox and this will show with every item in list using listview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three are two possibilities. If you are using default style means listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); then there is one solution.

If you are using custom adapter means in the layout you maintain two images one for normal and one for checked then there is other solution.

If you follow first way then this is the solution()...

http://www.ziddu.com/download/16103715/LvCheckBoxes.zip.html

If you are followed second way then let me know. I will give that example...

Comment: @ Harish : Thanks Your example is very useful. Now, i need a checkbox placing without using listview. How can i proceed this?

Comment: hey i didnot understand what you are telling. please tell me clearly....

Comment: www.androidcodesnips.blogspot.com. There you find some useful snips. Check that once

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using custom list adapter:  maintain a boolean flag and on button press make it true and call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` from there and in your adapter using this bool value set the checked or unchecked state of checkbox..